# How is strong coupling constant related to cross section?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, interactions, scattering-cross-section, strong-force

I've been looking through different Pdfs /articles on strong coupling constant and nearly all of them involve cross section, I've understood what cross section is but not how is it connected to coupling constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For comparison let us first look at [Rutherford scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rutherford_scattering),
which is caused by the electromagnetic interaction.
Its differential cross-section is given [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rutherford_scattering#Derivation) by:
$$\frac{d\sigma}{d\Omega}=
\left(\frac{Z_1Z_2\alpha\hbar c}{4E_\text{kin}\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2}}\right)^2$$
where

- $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are the charges (in units of $e$)
  of the incoming and the target particle,
- $\alpha\approx\frac{1}{137}$ is the dimensionless
  electromagnetic coupling constant
  (aka the [fine structure constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine_structure_constant)),
- $E_\text{kin}$ is the non-relativistic kinetic energy of the incoming particle,
- $\theta$ is the angle of deflection.

The important piece here is
$$\frac{d\sigma}{d\Omega} \propto \alpha^2,$$
meaning that the cross-sections get larger when the coupling constant is large.

This is not special to the electromagnetic interaction.
It will also hold for the strong interaction, except there you will have
the [strong interaction constant](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Forces/couple.html) $\alpha_\text{s}\approx 1$
instead of $\alpha\approx\frac{1}{137}$.
And of course, because the strong interaction doesn't obey Coulomb's law,
you will also get a different dependency on $\theta$.

Comment: thankyou so much1

Comment: can you also explain how structure functions are related to strong coupling constant? @thomasfritsch

Answer (score 0):

By scattering particles against one another one measures how these particles interact. In the context of QFT the strength of interactions is described by coupling constants. Hence by measuring the cross-section of scattering experiments one has a way to measure the coupling contants of the theory one believes
is describing the underlying process.